# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an old angular module which I use as the main module in a system.
Now- I would like to implement that module (**MyOldModule**) in a new angular skeleton\framework which use a different main module.
The **AdminLayoutComponent** is the main component.
The **MyOldModule** is the old module I would like to implement
The **OldComponent** is the problematic component which is not "familiar".

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'old-component'. (old-component is the selector name of the **OldComponent** )

This is the app.module:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        **RouterModule**,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MyOldModule //This is the "old" module I want to include
        })
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminLayoutComponent
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

This is the **routerModule**:

```
      const routes: Routes =[
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }, 
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'mycomponentPath',  //This is the "old" component located in my MyOld Module
            loadChildren: './OldModule/MyOld.module#MyOldModule'
          },
          {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
        }
        ]
       }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
           useHash: true
        })
      ],
      exports: [
      ],
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is **AdminLayoutModule**:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,

        MyOldModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ComponentA,
        ...

      ]
    })

    export class AdminLayoutModule {}
```

This is the MyOldModule:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        OldComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule, 
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MyOldRoutingModule,
      ],
      exports:[],
      providers: [MyService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class MyOldModule { }
```

this is **MyOldRoutingModule**:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'oldPath',  component: OldComponent }, 



    ]
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class MyOldRoutingModule { }
```

This is OldComponent:

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pages"  class="scroll"> </div>
```

Comment: Add BrowserModule to imports: [] in app.module

Comment: Thanks - it fixed that problem, but now I get:  Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component AdminLayoutComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `AdminLayoutModule` does not import `BrowserModule`. So add it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule, 
    MyOldModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ...

  ]
})

export class AdminLayoutModule {}
```